# unable to run the script in linux using plink

Tags: windows, shell-scripting, unix-shell, command-line-interface, plink

I'm unable to run a script in linux using `plink.exe`. I'm using my user **x** to login and script is under **y** user, which I need to sudo to **y** and run it. I was able to at command prompt manually but not through script (for automation).

```
plink.exe -v -t -l user(x) -pw ****** -ssh hostname "sudo su -y /abc/abc/start.sh"
```

its asking the password again. i was stuck there

```
Started a shell/command
[sudo] password for X:
```

Answer (score 1):

You could configure sudo on your remote host to allow user-X to execute your script without password authentication:

```
 #/etc/sudoers
 # or new include file in /etc/sudoers.d/

 user-X ALL=(user-Y) NOPASSWD: /abc/abc/start.sh
```

And normally you don't run `sudo` to execute `su` but switch directly to the user you want to run your commands as with something like:

```
 sudo -u user-Y  /abc/abc/start.sh
```